# Django Reduce the template Rendering Time

Tags: javascript, html, django, nginx

I am using Django 1.7 and nginx.

My sample view file is,

```
def testing(request):    
        return render_to_response('pages/testing.html',  )

def testing1(request):
        return render_to_response('pages/comingsoon.html',)

def testing2(request):
        x= User.objects.all()
        return render_to_response('pages/index1.html',{'users': x,})

def testing3(request):
        context = User.objects.all()
        return render_to_response('pages/testing.html',)
```

pages/testing.html - contains only text.(pure text)

pages/testing1.html - contains css and js

pages/testing2.html -

```
<body>
<h1>Users</h1>
{% for e in users %}

<table>
        <tr>
          <td class="active">{{ e.username }}</td>
          <td>{{ e.email }}</td>         
        </tr>
</table>
        {% endfor %}
</body>
```

pages/testing3.html - contains same as testing1.html

But while running this .

testing, testing1 take less than 3seconds in server.

But testing3 takes 40seconds and testing2 takes more that 1 Min.

How could I reduce that?
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: 1 min sounds a lot to me. How much of this time is queries?

Comment: Am having more queries for the same template, so it take more time.

Comment: @Wtower in queries it take some milliseconds only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) or [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

and specify the values you need in templates inside values_list or values, instead of User.objects.all(). This is going to make a huge diffrence.